# Jquery / Javascript calculate

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<!--

 var viewportwidth;
 var viewportheight;

 // the more standards compliant browsers (mozilla/netscape/opera/IE7) use window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight

 if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined')
 {
      viewportwidth = window.innerWidth,
      viewportheight = window.innerHeight
 }

// IE6 in standards compliant mode (i.e. with a valid doctype as the first line in the document)

 else if (typeof document.documentElement != 'undefined'
     && typeof document.documentElement.clientWidth !=
     'undefined' && document.documentElement.clientWidth != 0)
 {
       viewportwidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth,
       viewportheight = document.documentElement.clientHeight
 }

 // older versions of IE

 else
 {
       viewportwidth = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth,
       viewportheight = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight
 }
document.write('<style>.desktop{ height:'+viewportheight+'px;}</style>');
//-->
```

the output is

```
.desktop { height:687px;}
```

but its all viewport. I want it like this, height = +viewportheight+ - 30 = value. and I want to apply to .desktop like this .desktop { height:value;}

Update 1

i just try to edit like this.

```
if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined')
 {
      viewportwidth = window.innerWidth,
      viewportheight = window.innerHeight,
      height = viewportheight - 30,
      width = viewportwidth
 }

// IE6 in standards compliant mode (i.e. with a valid doctype as the first line in the document)

 else if (typeof document.documentElement != 'undefined'
     && typeof document.documentElement.clientWidth !=
     'undefined' && document.documentElement.clientWidth != 0)
 {
       viewportwidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth,
       viewportheight = document.documentElement.clientHeight,
      height = viewportheight - 30,
      width = viewportwidth
 }

 // older versions of IE

 else
 {
       viewportwidth = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth,
       viewportheight = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight,
      height = viewportheight - 30,
      width = viewportwidth
 }
document.write('<style>.desktop{ width:'+width+'px ;height:'+height+'px;}</style>');
```

and its work for me.
but if anyone here any better way, just tell me.

Comment: Please accept an answer or write your own answer and accept it to indicate that the problem is solved. See [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: oh, sory about that, i'll write it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i edit this and its work for me.

```
  if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined')
     {
          viewportwidth = window.innerWidth,
          viewportheight = window.innerHeight,
          height = viewportheight - 30,
          width = viewportwidth
     }

    // IE6 in standards compliant mode (i.e. with a valid doctype as the first line in the document)

     else if (typeof document.documentElement != 'undefined'
         && typeof document.documentElement.clientWidth !=
         'undefined' && document.documentElement.clientWidth != 0)
     {
           viewportwidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth,
           viewportheight = document.documentElement.clientHeight,
          height = viewportheight - 30,
          width = viewportwidth
     }

     // older versions of IE

     else
     {
           viewportwidth = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth,
           viewportheight = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight,
          height = viewportheight - 30,
          width = viewportwidth
     }
    document.write('<style>.desktop{ width:'+width+'px ;height:'+height+'px;}</style>'
```

i dont know about jquery / javascript syntax. but i try to figure it out.

i just add some line

```
 height = viewportheight - 30,
 width = viewportwidth
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
document.write('<style>.desktop{ height:' + (viewportheight - 30) + 'px;}</style>');
```

I believe that should subtract 30 from the viewportheight value

Comment: i was try like this height = viewportheight - 30, its work, but i'll try your way too. thanks :)

Comment: i dont know why, but your way is not work, so i try to do height = viewportheight -30 and i call in style like this .desktop { height: '+height+' px;} somethin' like that. and is work for me,

Comment: It is possible that you can't execute operations there it's good that you figured it out. Your way is just fine!! Thanks for posting the feedback / solution!